Gluon JavaFX WebView location not refreshed for iOS, and getHistory() throws NoSuchMethodError
Using Gluon to build a JavaFX mobile for iOS device, which consist of a Webview to display a hosted web application.
After deploying app to iOS device, first issue: WebEngine.locationProperty() doesn't always fire. We need to catch some of specific urls to apply certain logic.
Trying an alternative: see if I could poll web history instead to monitor the location: Deploying app to iOS device, and I got a NoSuchMethodError for  javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.getHistory()
Java 17,
Gluon-GraalVM: JavaFx17, 22.1.0.1
How can i resolve the above issue, or monitor for location changes
